# GitHub Webhook parse request object in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, github, webhooks

I would like to design and code a simple LaTeX CI environment. I need to parse request object that **GitHub Webhook** sends through HTTP POST for *push* and *pull request* events in **Express** (Node.js), but I can't find where it is located exactly.

[GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#pushevent) does not say where payload resides inside request object.

Also, how should JSON response be made? What HTTP code or JSON content should it have to communicate success or failure?

E.g.:

```
var app = express();

app.post('/build', function(req, res) {
  // request parsing
  // body
  // send response
});
```

Thanks in advance for response.

Comment: Check res.body (make sure you add the bodyParser middleware)

Comment: Thank you, @cmlndz! Question about request object solved.